# SQLite PHP PDO delete all rows in table

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

For some reason this throws a PDOException.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM ?');
$stmt->execute([$table]);
```

The error I get is "General error: 1 near "?": syntax error". I echoed `$table` right before `prepare` and it shows an existing table name.

I initialized `$db` like this.

```
 $db = new PDO("sqlite:my.db");
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);
```

I'm using PHP 5.4.4.

Comment: In prepared statements you can't use variables for anything that's a SQL identifier, like a table name or a column name.

Comment: @MikeW, Not only for MySQL, but for all databases

Comment: @Marcio - yes of course. It's about the fourth time I answered this today. I think I'm getting sleepy...

Comment: You can do `$table = "table_name";` then `DELETE FROM $table` but you can't use `?` or `:table`.